# show all pie chart together in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pie-chart

I have five data frames

```
               pt       car     walk    bike
Normal day     28.80    36.82   30.83   3.55
start          28.82    36.83   30.80   3.55
Equilibrium    28.51    36.95   30.98   3.56
Medium         31.74    33.80   32.23   2.23
Equilibrium2   32.06    34.04   30.78   3.12
```

that I with the following code

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(14, 10))
colors = ['yellowgreen','lightcoral','pink','lightskyblue']

for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    ax = axes[i // 3, i % 3]
    row = row[row.gt(row.sum() * .001)]
    #ax.pie(row, autopct='%1.1f%%',startangle=30, color=colors)
    ax.pie(row,  colors=colors,
                 autopct='%0.01f%%', startangle=30, pctdistance=0.7, radius=1)
    ax.set_title(idx)

    
#fig.legend(('pt','transit_walk','car', 'walk', 'bike'), prop={'size': 8}, title = 'Scenarios')
fig.legend(labels=df.columns,fontsize= 14,loc="center right")
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1, wspace=0.01)
```

I have produced this figure:
[image]

However, I want to have this picture:
[image]

How I can combine them?

Comment: Take a look at nested pie charts https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-nested-pie-py

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = ['yellowgreen','lightcoral','pink','lightskyblue']
size = 1/len(df.index)
yticks = []
yticklabels = []
for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    row = row[row.gt(row.sum() * .001)]
    ax.pie(row, 
        colors=colors, 
        radius=1-size*i,
        autopct='%0.01f%%',
        startangle=90,
        pctdistance=0.9,
        wedgeprops=dict(width=size),
        counterclock=False)
    yticks.append(i*size)
    yticklabels.append(idx)

ax.set_yticks(yticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(yticklabels)
fig.legend(labels=df.columns,fontsize= 14,loc="center right")
```

[image]